# How to iterate over every record in Firebase database in Python, Pyrebase

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using this library to access Firebase DB - https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase . There is a method there - each, but when I call it, my program hangs/gets killed.

```
all_objects = db.child(path).get().each()
```

I have the following data structure in firebase DB:

```
data{
   sub_folder{
          uniqueID:{data...},
          uniqueID:{data...},
          uniqueID:{data...},
          uniqueID:{data...},
          uniqueID:{data...},
          ......
     }
}
```

There is a lot of uniqueIDs with data there, like 20000. How do I iterate over every one of them?

How to correctly iterate over each record? I suspect that my implementation tries to fetch all records in one go.

Can I somehow fetch only a part of records and then page it with count/offset parameters?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over each data use a for loop:

```
**all_objects = db.child(path).get()
for obj in all_objects.each():
    print(obj.key())
```